# Does the inputAccessoryView have to be the top most view?

Tags: ios, inputaccessoryview

Is it possible to move the `inputAccessoryView` so that it's behind another view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation on [UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputAccessoryView), i don't think so.
`inputAccessoryViews` are attached to the keyboard, so unless the keyboard can be under another view, the `inputAccessoryView` can't.

You can though, create a normal view with the width of the keyboard, use the keyboard [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardWillShowNotification) to position your view on the screen right above the keyboard. Since this view won't be "attached" to the keyboard, you can put them under your desired view, for whatever effect you need.

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
```